# d3 stacked area string value xAxis

Tags: d3.js, stacked-area-chart

Is that possible to pass string values for x-Axis in d3 stacked area chart.
I tried two types of methods to pass string values for xAxis,

```
1) chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {

            var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d].x || 0;
  if (dx)
                return dx;    
            else 
                return '';

        });    


2) and also changed the .x(function(d){
return d[0];
})
```

second statement returning me the string value but while drawing the xAxis ticks are not visible and throws an error

in  stackedAreaChart.js

selection.each(function(data) {

Comment: The sloution is chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {

            var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d][0] || 0;
  if (dx)
                return dx;    
            else 
                return '';

        });